# Fitting row to oversized content with absolute position

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is an example of a row (in a list of rows), which has one row item that exceeds its height.

Setting `overflow: visible` did not solve this issue, since it only made the content visible without resizing the external DIVs, because `position: absolute` is set.

How to make the row (green border) adjust to its content?

It uses some CSS classes from Bootstrap and ideally should take use of the existing classes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-group panel-heading row" style="display: block; position: relative; line-height: 20px; border: 1px solid green">
  <div class="col-sm-2 switch-wrapper" style="overflow:visible; position:relative; border: 1px solid blue">
    <div style="overflow:visible; border: 1px solid yellow">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="border: 1px solid black"></i><span style=" position: absolute;margin-left: 5px; border: 1px solid red">A long description adjacent to the input field that doesn't fit into one line and it has to be broken into multiple lines.
    </span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want your text in blue border only?

Comment: if you remove `position:absolute` from `div` then content will be within green line

Comment: When an element is absolute, it is out of the "rendering flow", means other elements will not get interfered by the element.

Comment: @tkay is right, you need to do it manually or you can remove the ``position:absolute`` if it is not neccessary

Comment: The `position: absolute` is there because it the text should have its own margin, not influenced by the size of the arrow icon. Of course I'm thinking now about setting a fixed size to the `<i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="border: 1px solid black"></i>` and making the `position: absolute` unnecessary, as there is no straightforward solution apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an element is absolute, it is out of the "rendering flow",ignored by other elements. So you cannot change the parent div's size according to the absolute element. But you can always go for JavaScript solutions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//Initially set parent height = child height
$('.parent').height($('.child').height());
//set parent's height = child's height when window resizes
$(window).on('resize', function (){
    $('parent').height($('child').height()); 
})
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-group panel-heading row parent" style="display: block; position: relative; line-height: 20px; border: 1px solid green;padding-bottom:5px;">
  <div class="col-sm-2 switch-wrapper" style="overflow:visible; position:relative; border: 1px solid blue">
    <div style="overflow:visible; border: 1px solid yellow">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="border: 1px solid black"></i><span class="child" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 5px; border: 1px solid red">A long description adjacent to the input field that doesn't fit into one line and it has to be broken into multiple lines.
    </span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```